# MAC reverting back to original

Tags: linux

I'm trying to change MAC address on wlan0 USB device, so I write:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

And MAC doesn't change, I even modified the "NetworkManager.conf" as I read online. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ubuntu-how-to-change-mac-address-with-ifconfig-647323/) forum post I found, the man page for ifconfig explains it's only possible to change your MAC address using this method if your device supports it. As the poster said, my guess would be your device does not support this.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need a different one...

Comment: You might try using a different program, such as macchanger @Mr.Cohen